# How to implement a REST API which requires 256 MB of request size in GCP?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform

As far as I know, our options are:

Cloud Functions: 10 MB max.

Cloud Run: 32MB max. (HTTP 1.1) and unlimited if HTTP2. Our constraint is that we can't restrict this API to HTTP2 but we can have a proxy that can upgrade HTTP 1.1 requests to HTTP2

App Engine: 32MB max.

Cloud Storage: 5TB max. using a signed URL, but we can't use it since the API follows a specification that is different from the signed URL upload API (Different method, body, etc.)

How do we achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: 1) Uploading 256 MB takes a significant amount of time. You will pay for that time (runtime and memory). 2) I would never build an API that accepts 256 MB of data. Hackers will love you.  I would use an intermediary such as Cloud Storage (which you mentioned). 3) Network transfers for more than 50 - 100 MB are not reliable across most of the public Internet. If you control both the client and server, you will have a better experience, but end users will not unless you design for that. 4) Your best option is to use a service such as Compute Engine where you can control the network layer.

Comment: Did you look to perform multipart upload?